# Debian 8 unable to open port: 9042

Tags: debian, iptables, port, debian-jessie

I want to open port `9042`. But unfortunately the port is still closed

```
root@debian:/# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9042 --j ACCEPT
root@debian:/# iptables-save
```

output of `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9042
```

output of nmap `hostname`

```
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

output of `netstat -pln`

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7199            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1117/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59601         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1117/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1117/java
```

still I cannot connect to the port `9042`;

I tried with another port `5555` i still dont see the when i do `nmap` or `netstat`.

Comment: your process is only listening on 127.0.0.1. Configure your application to listen on 0.0.0.0.

Comment: ohh thanks i made the changes as you suggested... Its working again :)